Invalid expression
Here is my code
formatted_name = var.resource_type == "virtual_machine" ? format("vm-%s-00", substr(local.truncated_base_name, 0, 12)) :
                   var.resource_type == "key_vault" ? lower(format("kv-%s", var.base_name)) :
                   var.resource_type == "storage_account" ? lower(replace(format("sa%s", var.base_name), "-", "")) :
                   var.base_name

getting the following error
Error: Invalid expression
│ 
│   on ../modules/naming/main.tf line 4, in locals:
│    4:   formatted_name = var.resource_type == "virtual_machine" ? format("vm-%s-00", substr(local.truncated_base_name, 0, 12)) :
│    5:                    var.resource_type == "key_vault" ? lower(format("kv-%s", var.base_name)) :
│ 
│ Expected the start of an expression, but found an invalid expression token.
╵
╷
│ Error: Argument or block definition required
│ 
│   on ../modules/naming/main.tf line 5, in locals:
│    5:                    var.resource_type == "key_vault" ? lower(format("kv-%s", var.base_name)) :
│ 
│ An argument or block definition is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to introduce the argument value.

I tried different ways but keep still getting the same error, any help.

Wrap the expression on parenthesis:
formatted_name = (var.resource_type == "virtual_machine" ? format("vm-%s-00", substr(local.truncated_base_name, 0, 12)) :
                   var.resource_type == "key_vault" ? lower(format("kv-%s", var.base_name)) :
                   var.resource_type == "storage_account" ? lower(replace(format("sa%s", var.base_name), "-", "")) : 
                   var.base_name)

